# How is a stratified nonparametric test done in R (eg. coin package)

Tags: r

I'm trying to the coin (conditional inference) package to perform a stratified nonparametric test for difference in distribution (for count data).

I tried a stratified Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank sum test, which I think is called the van Elteren test:

```
wilcox_test(count ~ factor_of_interest | confounding_factor)
```

I also tried to do a stratified permutation test:

```
oneway_test(count ~ factor_of_interest | confounding_factor, distribution=approximate(B=10000))
```

**The problem is I can't find anywhere how the stratified version of these tests are performed. Does anyone know? For example, is a p-value calculated for each stratum and then the p-values combined (say, using Fisher's method)?**

By the way, the wilcox_test gave the following result:

```
Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
data:  n_coding_nonsilent by factor_of_interest
        stratified by confounding_factor 
Z = 2.1462, p-value = 0.03186 
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

Why would a nonparametric test like the Wilcoxon give a Z score?

This question was first asked on StackExchange but then marked as off-topic as it relates to R programming.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302007/how-is-a-stratified-nonparametric-test-done-in-r-eg-coin-package

Comment: Where does `oneway_test()` come from? Usually the documentation for these functions have a references section that points to the statistical description of the model. I think the question belongs on [stats.se] but wasn't phrased appropriately. I would first start by reading the documentation. If that doesn't help, then remove the explicit references to R in the title and code body. Then on Cross Validated ask more generally how you would do a stratified permutation test and maybe include `oneway_test` as an example of an R function that claims to do it but you don't know by which method.

Comment: oneway_test() is from the "coin" package in R. I've looked thru the documentation but there's very little information on the stratified version of the test.